# Create static overview sheet based on dynamic and changing source sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

**Short description of what I am looking for:**
A way to automatically import data from a dynamic Google Sheets document (using the Google Analytics add on) in another static Google Sheet, where the data will be automatically filled out in the right spot, but also stay there whenever the dynamic sheet changes.

**A bit of context:**
I am using Google's Analytics add on in Google Sheets (DOC1) to run reports about e.g. the number of users visiting my website every day. Due to the high amount of data, I can only run reports for about a month without sampling taking place.

For 2020 I would like to create an overview sheet (DOC2) to share with other people which gives an overview of the whole year. In other words, the cells of January in DOC2 should be filled when the data for January are rendered in DOC1. However, when data from February are being rendered in DOC1, the data from January should stay in DOC2.

I know it would be possible by copy and pasting the run reports to a non-dynamic sheet, but as I will need this for multiple parameters, this is not really a workable solution.

**What I've tried**
Multiple combinations of lookup and importrange functions, but the true difficulty stays in keeping the data once they are removed in the dynamic document. I have not found a solution to this problem yet...

Comment: "but the true difficulty stays in keeping the data once they are removed..." - for that you will need a script that will archive your range

Answer (score 0):

### If you are familiar with [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script), your request can be achieved with the method [setValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setValues(Object))

Sample:

```
function myFunction(){
var origin=SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID of origin Spreadsheet").getSheetByName("Name of the Sheet");
var destination=SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID of destination Spreadsheet").getSheetByName("Name of the Sheet");
var range=origin.getDataRange();
var values=range.getValues();
var A1notation=range.getA1Notation();
destination.getRange(A1notation).setValues(values);
}
```

Fill into the code the IDs of your origin and destination spreadsheets, as well as the correct names of the origin and destination sheets.

Links to other useful methods:

- [SpreadsheetApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app)
- [getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange)
- [getA1Notation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getA1Notation())
- [getValues](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)